# Paste is not worked in decimal field of asp.net web application in Mac/Safari

Tags: jquery, regex, macos, safari, copy-paste

I have an asp.net web application, in that application, I allowed only decimal in a few fields. It is working successfully on Google Chrome, Mozilla, Opera browser in Windows and Mac both OS but is not working in Safari browser in Mac OS.

To restrict string on **keypress** event, I used following regular expression:

```
var RegExp=  /^[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+$/
```

Why does this problem occur?

I will be grateful if anybody provides any idea of it.

Comment: `var RegExp= /^[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+$/`

Comment: actually i have used without inverted comma in RegExp. Are you sure that, copy/paste is not working due to regular expression syntax?

Comment: Maybe the name is equal to the class? What if you use `var reg = /^[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+$/`? Now, I am not sure  it is a dupe.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew why are you marked this question as duplicate? I am facing copy paste problem in Mac/Safari browser.

Comment: I closed it before you edited the question. Reopening now.